# Undefined method when building association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models as so:

```
Aceites belongs_to Warehouse
Warehouse has_many Aceites
```

These are my models:

```
class Warehouse < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :aceites
  validates :nombre, presence: true
end

class Aceite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :warehouse
  validates :nombre, presence: true
  validates :tipo, presence: true
  validates :stock, presence: true
  validates :warehouse_id, presence: true
end
```

Aceites controller (will put only crucial methods):

```
class AceitesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @aceite = Aceite.new
    end

    def create
        @aceite = Aceite.new(aceite_params)
        @warehouse = @aceite.warehouses.build(aceite_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            if @aceite.save
                format.html { redirect_to aceites_url, notice: "Product added!" }
                format.js
            else
                format.js
            end
        end
    end

    private

        def aceite_params
            params.require(:aceite).permit(:nombre, :tipo, :stock, :warehouse_id)
        end
end
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for(@aceite, remote: true, :html => { class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form' }) do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :nombre, class: 'form-control-label' %>
    <%= form.text_field :nombre, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :tipo, class: 'form-control-label' %>
    <%= form.text_field :tipo, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :stock, class: 'form-control-label' %>
    <%= form.number_field :stock, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :warehouse_id, class: 'form-control-label' %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:warehouse_id, Warehouse.all, :id, :nombre) %>
  </div>

  <%= form.submit @aceite.new_record? ? "Add Product" : "Edit Product", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

<% end %>
```

When I try to create a new `Aceite` (a product) associated to a `Warehouse`, I get the following error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
NoMethodError (undefined method `warehouses' for #<Aceite:0x00007f1141dfe2c0>
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: It is because there is no method `warehouses` defined on `Aceite` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you wrote:

```
@warehouse = @aceite.warehouses.build(aceite_params)
```

This line is the error. As you defined in the model that an `Aceite` belongs_to a `Warehouse`. But in the mentioned line you done the reverse. Your code reflects that a `Warehouse` belongs_to `Aceite`. So, the revised code would be:

**You are trying to build a warehouse. Which is incorrect.**

First, find the specific **Warehouse** (maybe you defined a nested route) :

```
@warehouse = Warehouse.find(params[:warehouse_id])
@aceite = @warehouse.aceites.new(aceite_params)
if @aceite.save
     ----- do something
end
```

If you don't define a nested route:

```
@aceite = Aceite.new(aceite_params) # in your aceite_params there is a warehouse_id, so the association will be done by rails
if @aceite.save
     ----- do something
end
```

Comment: Got it! It seems to work now, how can I access in the view for "Aceites" the warehouse name instead of ID? I have now aceite.warehouse_id. But I want to be able to show the name aceite.warehouse.name

Comment: get the specific `Aceite` object, like in the show page: `@aceite = Aceite.find(params[:id])`, and in the view `@aceite.warehouse.name`

Comment: Yes for the show page that makes sense, but for index? I have now `@aceites = Aceite.all` and if i put `@aceite = Aceite.find(params[:id])` it says cant find aceite withouth an ID.